# How do I reset the colors of my terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Help! Somehow my terminal looks like this:

[image]

It's nearly impossible to read the text. How can I fix it without exiting the terminal?

Comment: What the heck did you did to get it that way? xD

Comment: You can sometimes "accidentally" get this by using `cat` on a binary file.

Comment: I just tried to `cat` a binary file, was quite an experience...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The likely cause of this problem are [ANSI Escape Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). These allow scripts to change the foreground and background color of the terminal. You can even mimic the colors of the screenshot above by running the following command:

```
echo -e '\E[32;46m'
```

To reset the terminal colors, use the following command:

```
tput init
```

According to the manpage:

```
    init  If the terminfo database is present and an entry for the user's
          terminal exists (see -Ttype, above), the following will occur:

          (1) if present, the terminal's initialization strings will be
              output as detailed in the terminfo(5) section on Tabs and
              Initialization,

          (2) any delays (e.g., newline) specified in the entry will be
              set in the tty driver,

          (3) tabs expansion will be turned on or off according to the
              specification in the entry, and

          (4) if tabs are not  expanded, standard  tabs  will  be  set
              (every 8 spaces).

          If an entry does not contain the information needed for any of
          the four above activities, that activity will silently be
          skipped.
```

This should restore your terminal to its original colors.

Comment: Could you just close it and open it again?

Comment: Yes, but then all of my environment variables would be lost.

Comment: Good point. +1.

Comment: `reset` will also work but I think it'll also reset the environment variables.

Comment: The `reset` command will not reset the environment variables.

Comment: Can you please amend this answer to also cover `tput setaf 7 && tput setab 0` from comments further down? It helped me when `tput init` did not

Answer (score 28):

You can try this command also.It will  reset your terminal color.

```
tput sgr0
```

[image]

Comment: This one was the one that worked for me. The accepted answer did nothing, in my case.

Comment: The accepted answer also failed for me, both `echo -e '\E[32;46m'; tput init` did absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 6):

If you find your terminal in a state that none of `reset`, `tput init`, nor `tput sgr0` can fix, try `tput setaf 7 && tput setab 0` to force the text to white on black.

Comment: this worked on my vscode terminal when the other methods didn't

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it in my terminal as well, useful still!

Comment: `sgr0` is the code that will reset everything back to normal (Whatever normal is)