# My terminal went black, cannot see any text, how to reset its color?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, unity, themes, gnome-terminal

I know many people have asked for changing terminal's font color and I followed many methods, but they didn't work. I think my problem is quite serious...

This is how it looks like:

[image: my image]

A few months ago, I have installed a theme pack (I think from here www.noobslab.com/2014/04/macbuntu-1404-pack-is-released.html). Then recently I removed it. My folders icons looks a bit strange but the terminal still looks fine.

Things happened when today I tried to reset all display setting with a hope that everything would come back.. I saw this thread and followed the best answer. And then my terminal become all black...

I have tried solutions in these questions:

[How do I restore .bashrc to its default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404424/how-do-i-restore-bashrc-to-its-default)

[How do I reset the colors of my terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443560/how-do-i-reset-the-colors-of-my-terminal)

but they didn't work in my case.

Please help.. Thank you so much!

Comment: No I tried that solution but it didn't work. (edited)

Comment: Fair enough. Be sure to state what you have tried next time so that we don't go in circles.

Comment: I'll keep in mind. Thank you. I was too hurry to find a solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset the colors of my terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/443560/how-do-i-reset-the-colors-of-my-terminal)

Comment: Sorry for not mention it earlier, but I tried those solutions. they didn't work either. I'll update my question now.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, how stupid I was... It's easier than I think.

I just go to setting -> appearance. And choose theme Ambiance (default) then everything's back.